# calculate values from two form input and output to another form input while there are several inputs with the same IDs

Tags: javascript, laravel

The code structure is given below. These are generated by a for-each loop in Laravel. I am getting the products from an array, where lots of products may have. But I need to change the total of each products in view while I will change the quantity. The total need to be calculated from quantity and unit_price (quantity*unit_price). All the rest will remain same.

I want to do it using JavaScript. You anyone please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
   <input name="product_id" type="hidden" value="10" id="product_id">
   <input name="product_name" type="text" value="Product One" id="product_name">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
   <input name="quantity" type="number" value="1" id="quantity">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
   <input name="unit_price" type="number" value="500" id="unit_price">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
  <input name="total" type="number" value="500" id="total">
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-3">
   <input name="product_id" type="hidden" value="43" id="product_id">
   <input name="product_name" type="text" value="Product 2" id="product_name">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
   <input name="quantity" type="number" value="5" id="quantity">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <input name="unit_price" type="number" value="7" id="unit_price">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <input name="total" type="number" value="35" id="total">
</div>
```

This is the image of the view...
[image: This is the image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can accomplish this:

- First of all, you need to make sure your field ID's are unique, in your example above you have two fields with the same ID. This isn't immediately causing an issue, but it is a recipe for a future disaster.
- Add two data attributes to your fields, one `data-id=""` with the value of a unique row ID, this could be the primary key from the database, and one `data-field=""` with the name of that field.
- Add a class to both the quantity field and the unit price field so we can add an event listener to them `class="calculateRowTotal"`

With that done, you can now create an event listener that runs a function to calculate the row total. Here is what your event listener, and function, could look like:

```
var fieldsThatNeedListeners = document.getElementsByClassName('calculateRowTotal');

for(var x = 0; x < fieldsThatNeedListeners.length; x++) {
    fieldsThatNeedListeners[x].addEventListener('keyup', calculateRowTotal);
}

function calculateRowTotal(event) {
    var rowId = event.target.getAttribute('data-id');
    var quantity = document.querySelectorAll('[data-field="quantity"][data-id="' + rowId + '"]')[0];
    var price = document.querySelectorAll('[data-field="unit_price"][data-id="' + rowId + '"]')[0];
    var rowTotal = parseInt(price.value) * parseInt(quantity.value);
    document.querySelectorAll('[data-field="total"][data-id="' + rowId + '"]')[0].value = rowTotal;

}
```

Here is a working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/upxo34dn/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I will suggest wrap the HTML for one product in a div. Like belo I have wrapper that in a div with class `item_product`.

Secondly, I have changed `id="quantity"` to `class="quantity", same for`unit_price`and`total` as HTML should not contain multiple IDs with same name.

```
<div class="item_product">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
         <input name="product_id" type="hidden" value="10" id="product_id">
         <input name="product_name" type="text" value="Product One" id="product_name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <input name="quantity" type="number" value="1" class="quantity">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <input name="unit_price" type="number" value="500" class="unit_price">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <input name="total" type="number" value="500" class="total">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item_product">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <input name="product_id" type="hidden" value="43" id="product_id">
        <input name="product_name" type="text" value="Product 2" id="product_name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <input name="quantity" type="number" value="5" class="quantity">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <input name="unit_price" type="number" value="7" class="unit_price">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <input name="total" type="number" value="35" class="total">
    </div>
</div>
```

Then it can be done like below :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        $(document).on('blur', '.unit_price, .quantity', function(){

            var parent = $(this).closest('div.item_product');
            var quantity = $('.quantity', parent).val();
            var unitPrice = $('.unit_price', parent).val();

            $('.total', parent).val(parseInt(quantity) * parseFloat(unitPrice));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vrsboe9d/1/) for your reference